# Xamarin forms Combobox:SFComboBox!! How i can refresh my combobox?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, refresh

I'm trying to use CollectionChanged.

My code:

```
public List<RSSNotification> Notificacoes { get; private set; }
public RSSReader rssreader;
public List<RSSReader> feedsAdicionados = new List<RSSReader>();
ObservableCollection<string> comboFeeds = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ThirdPage(List<RSSReader> feed, List<RSSNotification> Not)
{
            InitializeComponent();
            mycombobox.ItemsSource = ComboFeeds;
            ComboFeeds.Clear();
            Notificacoes = Not;
            feedsAdicionados = feed;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < feedsAdicionados.Count; i++)
            {
                if (feedsAdicionados[i] != null) ComboFeeds.Add(feedsAdicionados[i].title);
            }
        }
```

```
private async void ButtonAdicionar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rssreader = new RSSReader();
            PopUp1 Pop = new PopUp1(0, rssreader, feedsAdicionados, Notificacoes);

            await Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(Pop);

            await DisplayAlert("Sucesso", "Feed Adicionado com sucesso",  "Ok" );

            Notificacoes = Pop.Notificacoes;
            rssreader = Pop.RSS;
            ComboFeeds.Add(rssreader.title);

            this.ComboFeeds.CollectionChanged += ComboFeeds_CollectionChanged;
        }
private void ComboFeeds_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
```

When the popup ends, I add it to my combobox via a class, then try to update, but it doesn't work.

Thx for all help

Comment: assigning an event handler *after* the event has occurred will not do anything useful.   And what is `ComboFeeds`?

Comment: Mr. @Jason  `ComboFeeds` is an ObservableCollection<string>.
I put in more code to make it easier to see.